# Views of Container Types

Tags: c++, c++20

According to http://eel.is/c++draft/range.view#concept:view , a `view` of a `range` is satisfied only when the range allows constant time move construction, move assignment, and destruction.

However, I'm wondering how a **container** item, such as std::map, can be converted to a `viewable_range`. The time complexity of the underlying red-black tree is O(log n) for typical operations rather than O(1).

The theory at: http://eel.is/c++draft/range.refinements#concept:viewable_range states that the `viewable_­range` concept specifies the requirements of a range type that can be converted to a view safely. *[The term 'safely' is a little ambiguous to understand]*

To put my question in another way, I'm wondering why does code like this compile without errors, wherein table_entries is considered as viewable_range but in theory it should not be since the time complexity is not O(1).

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>

auto main() -> int {

    std::map<int, int> table_entries;
    auto vals = std::ranges::min(table_entries | std::views::values);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You misread the first line in the first link. It's the `view` that needs to have O(1) operations, not the underlying range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion appears to be arising from this [line](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.view#1):

> The view concept specifies the requirements of a range type that has constant time move construction, move assignment, and destruction; ...

This doesn't mean that the underlying range that the view is constructed from needs to support constant time operations. It's only the view *itself* that needs to support constant time operations.

---

Note that the container `table_entries` is not a `view` itself (for the reasons you mentioned). However, `table_entries | std::views::values` *is* a `view` as it generates each value in the map, lazily and on demand.

Here's another example:

```
table_entries;                  // not a view
std::views::all(table_entries); // is a view
```

Comment: it's still unclear since the last example here: http://eel.is/c++draft/range.view#3 mentions `containers` and their associated destructors (rather than the view over it). If the `view` was the consideration rather than the `range`, then I believe `all` containers (std and custom) can be considered a viewable_range since the presence of a destructor wouldn't matter for a `view`.

Comment: @Jerry Added more explanation. Does that help?

Comment: Perfect. it helps. Now, I realize how I misread it wrong Thanks.